# Enterprise architect - Transformation Editor converting class to parts/properties

Tags: enterprise-architect

Is there a way to transform, using transformation editor (ctr+alt+h), a "class" to a "property of the class" using the Transformation editor in Enterprise Architect?

If i have this design:

Class1-|port1| <----Connector----> |port2|-Class2

i would like;

Property of class 1-|flowport1 from port1| <----Connector----> |flowport2 from port2|-Property of Class2

The current code looks like this (Class):

```
%if elemType=="Class"%
part
{
    %TRANSFORM_CURRENT("Class","stereotype")%
    %TRANSFORM_REFERENCE("Class",classGUID)%
    name=%qt%%className%%qt%
    stereotype = "Block"
    %list="InnerClass" @separator="\n" @indent="  "%
}

%elseIf elemType=="Port"%
    Port
    {
        %TRANSFORM_CURRENT("Class","stereotype")%
        %TRANSFORM_REFERENCE("Class")%
        stereotype = "FlowPort"

            %if classStereotype=="inPort"%
                Tag
                {
                    %list="InnerClass" @separator="\n" @indent="  "%
                    name = "direction"
                    value = "out"

                }


            %elseIf classStereotype=="OutPort"%
                Tag
                {
                    name = "direction"
                    value = "out"
                }
            %else%
                Tag
                {
                    name = "direction"
                    value = "inout"
                }
            %endIf%
        %list="Connector" @separator="\n" @indent="  "%
}
%endIf%
```

The current code takes all the classes from a design and makes new parts with "stereotype: Block". It also takes the design ports (defined as in-/outports) and changes their stereotype to flowports with correct direction.

Hope my explaination is sufficient
Thank you

Comment: Have you thought about using a script for the transformation? Personally I think that any language you know is by far better than this crappy EA macro language.